# How to remove item in Array?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am coding with **Swift**, and confuse with one problem.
I encountered *Index out of Range Error* when I am trying to remove one item from array during the array's enumeration.

Here is my error codes:

```
        var array :[Int] = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
        for (index, number) in array.enumerate() {
            if array[index] == 2 {
               array.removeAtIndex(index) // Fatal error: Index out of range
            }
        }
```

Does that means array.enumerate() not be called during each for loop?

I have to change my codes like that:

```
    for number in array {
       if number == 2 || number == 5 {
          array.removeAtIndex(array.indexOf(number)!)
       }
    }
```

Or

```
var index = 0
repeat {
    if array[index] == 2 || array[index] == 4 {
        array.removeAtIndex(index)
    }
    index += 1

} while(index < array.count)
```

Comment: Your count is 5 after removing index 2, but your index when you enumerate is having a count value of 6

Comment: do you want to remove multiple items or single item ?

Comment: I want to remove items match if condition.

Comment: @Happiehappie, I think each time of **FOR** loop check new array(I means removed result one.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are removing item at the same time when you are enumerating same array. Use filter instead:

```
var array: [Int] = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
array = array.filter{$0 != 2}
```

or, for multiple values, use `Set`:

```
let unwantedValues: Set<Int> = [2, 4, 5]
array = array.filter{!unwantedValues.contains($0)}
```

Same in one line:

```
array = array.filter{!Set([2, 4, 5]).contains($0)}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think filter can handle it. But, I have tried many times **for number in array** codes also can implement this. Maybe that means it different with **for (index, number) in array.enumerate()** . I am not sure it.

Comment: @noellee `enumerate()` method return new constant sequence, which will be same for all iterations. So, while you remove elements from original `array`, number of elements in this sequence keeps unchanged, causing out of reduced `array` range at the end. On other hand, `for number in array` use `array` dynamically, so there is no problem in this case, but I think it is bad style coding anyway.